# How to use environment variables in CloudFlare Worker in local development environment

Tags: environment-variables, cloudflare-workers

I have a CloudFlare Worker where I have environment variables set in the CF Settings..Environment Variables interface. I also have this wrangler.toml

[image: my wrangler.toml]

In my worker's index.js I have code reading the variable REGISTRATION_API_URL. If the code is running in a deployed environment then it injects the value from the CF Settings into REGISTRATION_API_URL just fine.

But if I run
`wrangler dev`
or
`wrangler dev --env local`
then REGISTRATION_API_URL is undefined.

Originally I expected that the variable would be populated by the CF Settings values, but they aren't. So I tried the two vars setting in the wrangler.toml I show here but no difference. And I have spent a lot of time searching the docs and the greater web.

Are environment variables supported in a local dev environment? Any workarounds that people have come up with? Currently I am looking for undefined and defining the variable with a hard-coded value, but this is not a great answer.

Using wrangler 1.16.0

Thanks.

Comment: According to the [Cloudflare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environments/#introducing-environments) what you're doing should work. I just tried this with [Wrangler2](https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler2) (currently in beta) but wasn't able to achieve what I wanted. Have you tried the newer version?

Comment: Thanks,  no we decided it wasn't worth the problems we were having and moved to a different solution.

Answer (score 9):

The docs could be more clear IMO but if you are using the newer module syntax, the variables will not be available as global variables.

> ### [Environmental variables with module workers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables/#environmental-variables-with-module-workers)
>
> When deploying a Module Worker, any [bindings](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables/) will not be available as global runtime variables. Instead, they are passed to the handler as a [parameter](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables/#parameters) – refer to the `FetchEvent` [documentation for further comparisons and examples](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/fetch-event/#bindings-1) .

Here's an example.

```
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, context) {
        return new Response(env.MY_VAR);
    }
};
```

KV namespaces are also available in the same object.

Comment: It saves my day! Thanks a lot. CF definitely should update their documents.

Comment: OMG, I've lost two days trying to manage this issue. Cloudflare must update their poor documentation.

Comment: New way is through a `.dev.vars` file, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The new way to do it is actually through `.dev.vars` file which should be written as any dotenv file.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/configuration/secrets/

This will get picked up by the dev server, for prod push the secrets to the CF dashboard via the `wrangler secret put SECRET_NAME` command

Answer (score -2):

Maybe a bit late, but: no I don't think you can

But: you can always use self["YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE"] to get the value and then go from there (unfortunately the docs don't mention that)

Here is what I personally do in my Workers Site project to get the Release version (usually inserted via pipeline/action and then inserted via HtmlRewriter into the index.html):

```js
const releaseVersion = self["RELEASE_VERSION"] || 'unknown'
```